# Why my program is executing both if and else?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

My program is responding in a very weird way. When I click the button and `selectService()` is called then it processes correctly, but the final if/else statements behave weirdly in that it shows messages of both the `if` and `else` part. Sometimes it shows the old messages and then new.

```js
var i = 0;

function selectService() {
  $("#tblServices tr").filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function() {
    //i = 1; // to check if the looping has been done or not
    //alert(i);

    var url = '@Url.Action("CreateInvoice")';
    var data = {
      fk_BookingID: $("#Booking_ID").val(),
      fk_ServiceID: $("td:eq(0)", this).text()
    }

    $.post(url, data, function(response) {
      if (response.ReturnStatusJSON === true) {
        alert(response.ReturnStatusJSON);
        return true;
      } else {
        swal("Sorry !", response.ReturnMessageJSON, "error");
        return false;
      }
    });

    i = 1;
  });

  if (i === 0) {
    swal("Sorry !", "You must select at least one service", "error");
    return;
  }

  if (i > 0) {
    var url2 = '@Url.Action("UpdateBookingInvoiceGeneration")';
    var data2 = {
      Booking_ID: $("#Booking_ID").val()
    }

    $.post(url2, data2, function(response) {
      if (response.ReturnStatusJSON === true) {
        swal("Done", response.ReturnMessageJSON, "success");
        $('.selectColumn').prop("checked", false);
        return;
      } else {
        swal("Sorry !", response.ReturnMessageJSON, "error");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

What's going on? Why does it behave this way? I am using the latest version of Chrome.

Update:

I saw a very different kinda problem upon debugging. I selected 3 checkboxes in the table upon which **each loop** is supposed to be run 3 times at least, but it ran for 2 times at first and jumped to **if(i>0)**, executed that fully and again jumped to select services function and ran for the 3rd check, the remaining one.

Comment: It's not clear what you're describing.  For one thing, your AJAX call is being made in a loop.  So why aren't you expecting it to be made multiple times?  As for the if/else, the one thing we can guarantee you is that any given instance of that code *is absolutely not* executing both of those blocks.  But since you're executing that code multiple times with potentially different runtime values, what you're seeing sounds like expected behavior.  So what specifically is the problem?

Comment: It can't be from the same HTTP request, so I'm guessing it's either a new request from the `.each()` or the `selectService()` being called twice. Try adding some logs :)
PS. pretty sure you can do `if (response.ReturnStatusJSON)` only

Comment: @David even sometimes the each loop exists without looping over the multiple rows but sometimes it executes completely

Comment: @mtefi: tried that but same issue

Comment: @Stacky: I'm not sure what that comment is even supposed to mean.  But one thing I am sure of is that you need to debug and reduce the problem.  When something specific and unexpected is happening, that's where you debug.  Identify what exactly is happening in the debugger.  On what specific line of code does something unexpected happen?  What were the inputs?  What were you expecting to happen?  Why?

Comment: if (i > 0) this block is creating the problem

Comment: @Stacky: Ok, and what is "the problem" in that case?  What are you expecting `if (i > 0)` to do for any given value of `i`?

Comment: @David: i saw a very weird problem upon debugging. 

I selected 3 checkboxes in the tables upon which the each loop is supposed to be run 3 times atleast, but it ran for 2 times and jumped to if(i>0) executed that and again jumped to select services function and ran for the 3rd check

Comment: You're aware `$.post` is an asynchronous method?

Comment: @Teemu: yes, though i am very new to it but i know, so how to handle this behaviour?

Comment: @David: did u see my comment?

Comment: It looks like you'd expect returnings from the first post done handler to break the each loop. They don't, the loop is executed a way before the first AJAX call runs the done handler. That means, that `i` is never `0` in the condition of the first `if`. This also means, that the second `if` always passes (`i` is always `1`) at the time the `if` runs. Then comes the odd part, what are `response.ReturnStatusJSON` and `response.ReturnMessageJSON`, `$.post` here is not jQuery post?

Comment: the `return` statements in the callbacks from your $.post method don't do anything useful, if that's what you were hoping (although it's still not entirely clear). In that context there's nothing to return to. They don't break your loop, nor do they cause your outer function to return. In fact since the ajax calls are asynchronous, your loop and the outer function will already have completed by the time the code which handles response from the ajax call is executed.

Comment: @Teemu: used  $.ajaxSetup({ async: false }); this and worked

Comment: @Stacky `async:false` is deprecated in some browsers, you'll see a warning in the console when you use it, and so you can expect it may stop working in future. Because of the single-threading it locks the browser UI entirely during the request, which, if it's unexpectedly long for some reason, could cause the user to think the whole browser has crashed. It also obviously slows down your page for the same reason. Those are the main reasons its deprecated. This may provide you with a quick fix but I strongly recommend you plan to refactor your code soon to work without it.

Answer (score 1):

I think I kind of understand what you're trying to do, and using a variable to check if the block inside `.each` has been executed is bad practice. Same goes for using synchronous requests.

So here's a suggestion, hope it helps

```js
function selectService() {

    // First, manage the case where the user didn't select a service
    if ($("#tblServices tr").filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)') === null) { // or check array length
        swal("Sorry !", "You must select at least one service", "error");
        return;
    }

    // Then, if he has
  $("#tblServices tr").filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function() {
    var url = '@Url.Action("CreateInvoice")';
    var data = {
      fk_BookingID: $("#Booking_ID").val(),
      fk_ServiceID: $("td:eq(0)", this).text()
    }

    // Do your first request
    $.post(url, data, function(response) {
      if (response.ReturnStatusJSON === true) {
        alert(response.ReturnStatusJSON);

        var url2 = '@Url.Action("UpdateBookingInvoiceGeneration")';
        var data2 = {
          Booking_ID: $("#Booking_ID").val()
        }
    
        // Still in the callback, do the second one if you want it done AFTER
        // getting the result for the first one
        $.post(url2, data2, function(response) {
          if (response.ReturnStatusJSON === true) {
            swal("Done", response.ReturnMessageJSON, "success");
            $('.selectColumn').prop("checked", false);
            return;
          } else {
            swal("Sorry !", response.ReturnMessageJSON, "error");
          }
        });

        return true;
      } else {
        swal("Sorry !", response.ReturnMessageJSON, "error");
        return false;
      }
    });

  });

}
```

Comment: "Same goes for using asynchronous requests"...did you mean "Same goes for using **synchronous** requests"?